# How to have a page redirect on a 400 bad request in api call? In Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to add a page redirect to when I get a 400 bad request from an api call. Where would I do this? In the service or the component.ts: My code so far is:

**Service.ts**

```
  getIncidents(customerId): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.get<any>(this.incidentApiUrl + "?customer_id=" + customerId)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

**Component.ts**

```
private getIncidents() {
    this.service.getIncidents(this.customer_id).subscribe((data) => {
      this.loading = true;
      console.log('Data' + data);
      this.showTable = this.data = data.result;
      this.loading = false;
      console.log('Result - ', data);
      console.log('data is received');
      this.errorApi = data.result == null || data.result === 0 || data.result.length === 0;
    })
  }
```

Comment: You can do this in `Interceptor`: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

Comment: Do you have code example?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8) can be a starting point

Answer (score 3):

You can create ErrorInterceptor from HttpInterceptor

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';



@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
            if (err.status === 400) {
                // redirect to some page
                 this.router.navigate(['/somepage']);
            }
            const error = err.error || err.statusText;
            return throwError(error);
        }))
    }
}
```

and add the same in the providers of the module

```
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true },
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you may handle it on your component. This is because the [.subscribe()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/subscribe.html) method accepts 3 arguments/methods.

> onNext-  An Observable calls this method whenever the Observable emits
>   an item. This method takes as a parameter the item emitted by the
>   Observable.
>
> onError -  An Observable calls this method to indicate that it has
>   failed to generate the expected data or has encountered some other
>   error. This stops the Observable and it will not make further calls to
>   onNext or onCompleted. The onError method takes as its parameter an
>   indication of what caused the error (sometimes an object like an
>   Exception or Throwable, other times a simple string, depending on the
>   implementation).
>
> onCompleted -  An Observable calls this method after it has called
>   onNext for the final time, if it has not encountered any errors.

Knowing that, we can redirect our users on the `onError` callback

```
this.service.getIncidents(this.customer_id).subscribe((data) => {
      this.loading = true;
      console.log('Data' + data);
      this.showTable = this.data = data.result;
      this.loading = false;
      console.log('Result - ', data);
      console.log('data is received');
      this.errorApi = data.result == null || data.result === 0 || data.result.length === 0;
    }, error => {
      this.router.navigate(['/handle']);
    })
```

Comment: Does that work if there is a 400 bad request or just any error?

Comment: @Sole Yes it does! It catches all the error 40x and 50x! You can test it out. Let me know how it goes?