# How to add error page redirect in http service for Angular

Tags: angular

I want to add a error page redirect for a 400 bad request in my service for api calls: my code is as follows:

**service.ts:**

```
    getIncidents(customerId): Observable<any> {
       return this.http.get<any>(this.incidentApiUrl + "?customer_id=" + customerId)
          .pipe(
            catchError(this.handleError)
          );
      }

   private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.log(error.error.message)

    } else {
      console.log(error.status)
    }
    return throwError(
      console.log('Something is wrong!'));
  };

}
```

Where can I put the redirect in here??

Comment: Inside the `else` where's `console.log(error.status)` ask if `status===400` and then `router.navigate(['my','bad_request','page'])`

Comment: Do you have an example code for answer?

Answer (score 0):

You should create an Global Error Handler. I implement this way.

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    constructor(private logService: LoggerService, private router : Router) {

    }
    handleError(error) {

    if(error.status == 404){
      this.router.navigate(['/error-page']);
    }
  }
}
```

And add to providers in `NgModule`

```
  provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},
   {
        provide: ErrorHandler, 
        useClass: GlobalErrorHandler
   }
```

Comment: OK where would this be placed?

Comment: as  i have answered in your previous question you can create this GlobalErrorHandler as a helper and keep it in src/helpers folder and  you need  to include it in the module you need  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55417987/how-to-have-a-page-redirect-on-a-400-bad-request-in-api-call-in-angular/55418146#55418146

Comment: He is using ErrorHandler

Comment: @HienNguyen sorry just a typo ,  i just what to convey that it can be placed in helpers folder

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an example right now but you can.

First inject the router via your component's constructor like:

```
constructor(private router: Router){...}
```

and then, in your handle error function do something like:

```
private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.log(error.error.message)
    } else {
       if (error.status === 400) {
           this.router.navigate(['my','bad_request','page']);
       } else {
           // ....
       }
    }
    return throwError(
      console.log('Something is wrong!'));
  };
```

Comment: I get ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can definitey use `Router` service inside your error handing method to redirect the user to the error component page.

Don't forget to inject the `Router` service in the constructor as

```
constructor(private _router: Router) { }
```

And handle it in error method as

```
HandleError() {
    _router.navigate('[error]',{ 'errorCode' :this.errorCode }); 
    //Pass optional parameter to share the error code and handle it in that page
}
```